# Import Object of arrays from CSV to Neo4j

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv, neo4j

I have a collection in mongo that I need to migrate to Neo4j. To do that, I will export it to CSV. Then, I'll import the resultant CSV to Neo4j using Cypher. The documents from the collection have an object with an array that contains objects with arrays inside them. Take a look at the JSON above:

```
"services" : [
            {
                "max_id" : "646767779849326594", 
                "log" : [
                    {
                        "date" : 1443024000, 
                        "steps" : 6
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : 1442512800, 
                        "steps" : 1
                    }
                ], 
                "service" : "home_timeline"
            }, 
            {
                "max_id" : 0.0, 
                "log" : [
                    {
                        "date" : 1443024000, 
                        "steps" : 4
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : 1442512800, 
                        "steps" : 1
                    }
                ], 
                "service" : "user_timeline"
            }, 
            {
                "max_id" : 0.0, 
                "log" : [
                    {
                        "date" : 1443024000, 
                        "steps" : 6
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : 1442512800, 
                        "steps" : 1
                    }
                ], 
                "service" : "mentions_timeline"
            }
        ]
```

How can I import this to Neo4 properly?? I already found a solution to import arrays. But I didn't find nothing similar to my problem. How should be the header of the CSV? How should be the Cypher code to get these objets??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON as a parameter to a Cypher query. There are a few examples of this [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/) and [here](https://github.com/johnymontana/SWAPI-graph/blob/master/SWAPI.ipynb).

With your example something like this:

```
WITH {json} AS data
UNWIND data.services AS service
// Insert data for each service.
MERGE (s:Service { "service_name": service.service})
SET s.max_id = service.max_id
FOREACH (log IN service.logs | CREATE (l:Log {date: log.date, steps: log.steps})<-[:LOGGED]-(s))
```

There is also a tool for translating data from MongoDB document data model to Neo4j property graph model that you might find useful: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager

Comment: Thanks, William! I'll take a look at this!